# How can I change the color a label on a bar chart?

Tags: extjs4.1

Using the example from the docs Ext.chart.series.Bar it should be pretty easy to achieve this.

The series has a label config that contains a color properties. Changing this has no effect. Or am I missing something?

I would like to display a white text on top of the bars.

Working code for the example
http://jsfiddle.net/dfDb8/

On line 48 I try to set the color to white

```
    label: {
      display: 'insideStart',
        field: 'data',
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0'),
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        color: '#fff' //this is what I want to change
        'text-anchor': 'middle'
    },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The following attribute:

```
fill: '#fff'
```

seems to work. I am not completely sure why though.

Comment: I haven't tried fill. I partially does what I want except for the situations when the bar length is small and the label is displayed on the right side. I tried to use also the contrast: true property together with fill to fix this. But when contrast is used together with fill nothings happens.
Maybe the implementation is not complete.

Comment: @bbb Did you get this figured out? (I know very late response but I am currently reviewing my stackoverflow answers)